# How to access a specific table in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a docx document with 10 tables. I want to access table 3, 4, 8 and 9 to color the content of the table. How can I access a specific table via VBA?

I know this code will access all tables, but instead of all, I just want to use my code on specific tables:

```
Dim oTbl As Word.Table
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
```

The code right now will color a table, which is in my focus:

```
Sub colourSelectedTable()

Dim c As Word.Cell

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
  For Each c In Selection.Tables(1).Range.Cells

    If InStr(c.Range.Text, Chr(37)) > 0 And Val(c.Range.Text) >= 110 Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(255,124,103)

    ElseIf InStr(c.Range.Text, Chr(37)) > 0 And Val(c.Range.Text) < 0 Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(255,124,103)

    ElseIf InStr(c.Range.Text, Chr(37)) > 0 And Val(c.Range.Text) <= 100 Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(136,241,142)

    ElseIf InStr(c.Range.Text, Chr(37)) > 0 And Val(c.Range.Text) > 100 And Val(c.Range.Text) < 110 Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(255,227,132)

    ElseIf Val(c.Range.Text) = "Good" Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(136,241,142)  

    ElseIf Val(c.Range.Text) = "Fair" Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(255,227,132)  

    ElseIf Val(c.Range.Text) = "Satisfactory" Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(255,227,132)  

    ElseIf Val(c.Range.Text) = "Not Satisfactory" Then
    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = rgb(255,124,103)  

  End If

  Next
  End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveDocument.Tables(i)` to access ith Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most collections like Tables, Paragraphs, etc. can be accessed by number : [`Document.Tables(1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table)

```
Dim i As Long, c As Word.Cell, doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

For i = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
    If i = 3 Or i = 4 Or i = 8 Or i = 9 Then
        For Each c In doc.Tables(i).Range.Cells
            ' your code here 
        Next
    End If
Next
```